# Connecting UISwitch in Storyboard to preexisting Outlet and IBAction

Tags: ios, xcode

I designed static UITableViewController using Storyboard. I have 2 Storyboard, one for English and another one for different Language.

I've connected some UISwitch in  Storyboard to Outlet and IBAction in UITableViewController using Ctrl-mouse drag.

The issue, I completed this task for "English" Storyboard, and I need to do the same for other other language Storyboard.

my understanding, if I used Ctrl-mouse drag, it will create "NEW" Outlet and IBAction. However, I just need to use pre-existing Outlet and IBAction.

So How I connect UISwitch with the already existing Outlet and IBAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection exists per storyboard.

So when you make the connection again for a localized storyboard in another language, that's the one connection the app will go with.  If running in Hindi, for example, the English storyboard will be ignored.

The outlet exists because you declared it in your object's "`@interface`".  The connection is what you're making by control-dragging from the object to the item in the view.